# Iniciar animacion con evento hover en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Estoy realizando una animación de un frame sencilla, pero quiero que la animación inicie cuando el cursor este sobre el frame y regrese a su forma inicial cuando salga de el frame.

Ya que por el momento solo funciona con un boton, este es mi codigo

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QPushButton,QFrame
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QPropertyAnimation
from PyQt5 import uic

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)


        self.boton = QPushButton("animacion",self)
        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.anima)

        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.frame.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Panel | QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setGeometry(100,100,30,50)

    def bot(self):
        print("click")

    def anima(self):
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.frame,b"geometry")
        self.anim.setDuration(100)
        self.anim.setStartValue(QRect(100,100,30,50))
        self.anim.setEndValue(QRect(100,100,90,50))
        self.anim.start() 


app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.resize(300,300)
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

y podrian explicarme **b"geometry"** que otros valores pueden colocar en vez de este en la animación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea una clase que herede de `QFrame` y reimplementa [QWidget.enterEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enterEvent) y [QWidget.leaveEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#leaveEvent) en ella:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QPushButton,QFrame
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QPropertyAnimation
from PyQt5 import uic

class MyFrame(QFrame):

     def enterEvent(self, QEvent):
        anim = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"geometry")
        anim.setDuration(100)
        anim.setStartValue(QRect(100,100,90,50))
        anim.setEndValue(QRect(100,100,30,50))
        anim.start() 


     def leaveEvent(self, QEvent):
        anim = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"geometry")
        anim.setDuration(100)
        anim.setStartValue(QRect(100,100,30,50))
        anim.setEndValue(QRect(100,100,90,50))
        anim.start() 



class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.frame = MyFrame(self)
        self.frame.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Panel | QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setGeometry(100, 100, 30, 50)



app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.resize(300,300)
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

También puedes generar tu propia señal:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QPushButton,QFrame
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QPropertyAnimation, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5 import uic

class MyFrame(QFrame):    
    mouseHover = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.mouseHover.emit(True)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.mouseHover.emit(False)



class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.frame = MyFrame(self)
        self.frame.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Panel | QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setGeometry(100, 100, 30, 50)
        self.frame.mouseHover.connect(self.hover_anim)


    def hover_anim(self, hovering):
        anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.frame, b"geometry")
        anim.setDuration(100)
        if hovering:
            anim.setStartValue(QRect(100,100,90,50))
            anim.setEndValue(QRect(100,100,30,50))
        else:
            anim.setStartValue(QRect(100,100,30,50))
            anim.setEndValue(QRect(100,100,30,50))
        anim.start() 



app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.resize(300,300)
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto "geometry" hace referencia a la [propiedad del widget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#properties) objetivo de la animación. Tienes la posibilidad de crear tus propias propiedades (`pyqtProperty`) en la subclase de tu widget para implementar otras animaciones, como por ejemplo cambiar el color.